Test SpringBoot Webclient in Groovy throwsNullPointerException in put call
I am testing a Java method that uses Spring Boot WebClient to make a PUT request and returns void. The test is written in Groovy. This is the method I want to test:
public void putProcessing(final Auth auth, final TokenParser jwtParser, final String processing) {
    final String functional = AuthUtils.getFuncional(auth, jwtParser); // I have a mocked String here
    final CacheApiRequest cacheApiRequestBody = this.cacheApiRequestBodyMapper.map(processing, this.ttl); // I also have a mocked CacheApiRequest here
    this.webClient.put() // webclient is mocked here
            .uri(this.uriBase, // nullpointer exception here
                    uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/").path(this.uriCacheLoading).path(this.valuePathKey)
                            .build(Utils.getFuncionalToogle(functional)))
            .header(TokenEnum.INFOSIG.getName(), auth.getInfoSig())
            .header(TokenEnum.AUTHENTICATION.getName(), auth.getAuthentication())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(Mono.just(cacheApiRequestBody), CacheApiRequest.class)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(Void.class).block();
}

And this is the class with the test method
@SpringBootTest
class CacheCarteiraRepositoryImplITSpec extends SpringBootSpec {

CacheCarteiraRepositoryImpl repository;
WebClient webClientMock = Mock(WebClient)
CacheApiRequestBodyMapper cacheMapper = Mock(CacheApiRequestBodyMapper)

def setup() {
    println "Initializing test setup"
    
    FixtureFactoryLoader.loadTemplates("com.foo.fixtures")
    repository = new CacheCarteiraRepositoryImpl(webClientMock, cacheMapper)

    repository.uriBase = "http://localhost:8080";
    repository.maxAttepts = 3L;
    repository.delay = 2L;
    repository.uriCacheLoading = "/api";
    repository.uriCacheData =  "/test";
    repository.ttl = 1L;
    repository.valuePathKey = "/abc";
    
    println "Setup completed"
}

@Unroll
def "must call putProcessing"() {
    println "Entering the test putProcessing"
    
    given: "a valid auth"
    Auth auth = Fixture.from(Auth.class).gimme("VALID")

    and: "a valid tokenParser"
    TokenParser jwtParser = Mock(TokenParser)

    and : "a mocked claims "
    Claims claims = Mock(Claims)
    claims.get("codigoFuncional", String.class) >> "1234-56"
    jwtParser.getBody("valid.jwt.token") >> claims

    and: "a mocked CacheApiRequest "
    CacheApiRequest cacheApiRequestMock = new CacheApiRequest("true", 1L)
    cacheMapper.map("true", 1L) >> cacheApiRequestMock

    WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec bodySpec = Mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec)
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec headerSpec = Mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec)
    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = Mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec)
    
    println "mocking webclient put method"

    webClientMock.put() >> bodySpec
    bodySpec.uri(_,_) >> bodySpec
    bodySpec.header(_,_) >> bodySpec
    bodySpec.contentType(_) >> bodySpec
    bodySpec.bodyValue(_) >> headerSpec
    headerSpec.retrieve() >> responseSpec
    responseSpec.bodyToMono(Void.class)>>  Mono.empty()

    when: "call putProcessing"
    println "Starting putProcessing"
    repository.putProcessing(auth, jwtParser, "true")

    then: "the webClient.put() is called"
    1 * webClientMock.put()

    println "test completed"
}

This is the error:
[INFO] Running com.foo.Test
Initializing test setup
Setup completed
Entering the test putProcessing
mocking webclient put method
Starting putProcessing
 <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$RequestBodyUriSpec.uri(String, java.util.function.Function)" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.put()" is null
        at com.foo.Test.putProcessing...



A few things other than what @kriegaex already said. Use a Mock if you need to assert something, otherwise prefer to use a Stub it makes it easier for the reader to see what is important. Stubs also return themselves if the return type matches their type, so you can remove some of those bodySpec instructions. If you have strongly typed fields then you can omit the class parameter, e.g., Claims claims = Mock().

I did not try to run your code, because probably lots of classes are missing anyway. But I noticed the classical Spock user problem of trying to separate mocking and stubbing instead of doing them simultaneously as described in the Spock manual:
You did:
webClientMock.put() >> bodySpec
// ...
1 * webClientMock.put()

You should do:
1 * webClientMock.put() >> bodySpec

